# Alternative to java.net.URL for custom timeout setting

Tags: java, url, timeout

Need timeout setting for remote data request made using java.net.URL class. After some googling found out that there are two system properties which can be used to set timeout for URL class as follows.

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout  
sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout
```

I don't have control over all the systems and don't want everybody to keep setting the system properties. Is there any other alternative for making remote request which will allow me to set timeouts.
Without any library, If available in java itself is preferable.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you're opening a `URLConnection` from `URL` you can set the timeouts this way:

```
URL url = new URL(urlPath);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
con.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```

How are you using the `URL` or what are you passing it to?

Comment: He's likely plain calling `URL#openStream()` which will indeed use the default timeouts.

Comment: read timeout works perfectly, but connect timeout seams does not work

Answer (score 2):

A common replacement is the [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), it gives much more control over the entire process of fetching HTTP URLs.