# Network is unreachable?

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I want to run a cyc (opencyc) Java class, but when I run this class I got an error mentioning that the network is unreachable. I am working on NetBeans 7.0 and opencyc 2.0 win 32 version. I am using localhost (127.0.0.1) to test. The error is below.

```
Network is unreachable: connect
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
at org.opencyc.api.CycConnection.initializeApiConnections(CycConnection.java:223)
at org.opencyc.api.CycConnection.<init>(CycConnection.java:199)
at org.opencyc.api.CycAccess.<init>(CycAccess.java:121)
at org.opencyc.api.CycAccess.<init>(CycAccess.java:61)
at org.opencyc.api.ApiDemo.<init>(ApiDemo.java:50)
at org.opencyc.api.ApiDemo.main(ApiDemo.java:147)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.opencyc.api.ApiDemo.<init>(ApiDemo.java:56)
at org.opencyc.api.ApiDemo.main(ApiDemo.java:147)
Interruption while waiting Cyc connection establishment, closing sockets
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.opencyc.api.CycConnection$TaskProcessorBinaryResponseHandler.access$002(CycConnection.java:988)
at org.opencyc.api.CycConnection.close(CycConnection.java:268)
at org.opencyc.api.CycConnection$ConnectionTimer.run(CycConnection.java:1351)
```

Why is this happening? How can I connect to the cyc?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826331/java-net-socketexception-network-is-unreachable-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same version I have, it's trying to establish a connection to a Cyc image with the hostname and port defined by

CycConnection.DEFAULT_HOSTNAME
CycConnection.DEFAULT_BASE_PORT

You can find the proper values to use by evaluating the following in your Cyc image:

```
(get-machine-name)
*BASE-TCP-PORT*
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you David... :) But why is it not working for localhost?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your network settings do not allow you to connect to this machine. This is not a Java problem as such.

try

```
ping {hostname}
```

until this works, there is nothing you can do in java to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

A dev on my team encountered this today, only their machine is seeing this issue out of many on the team.

Through much debugging we eventually discovered that `localhost` would not resolve for some reason. It would work in some JVM contexts and fail in others so it was completely inconsistent.

Replacing `localhost` with explicitly `127.0.0.1` fixed the issue. My hunch is that something was different with a local network and IPv6 perhaps, but we still don't really understand why this is the fix.