# Could not connect to SMTP host: IP address, port: 25; Caused by: java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, email

The email program worked perfectly fine with the SMTP server of my company. The SMTP server changed, and I only changed the hostname configuration of my email program. We have tested the mail server and we are sure it is possible to send an email from there to our email addresses. My application is written in java, and uploaded on Tomcat Server. This server is able to ping the mail server, and telnet works from this server.

I really want to know why I am getting the following exception, thanks for any guidance.

I am getting the exception of javax.mail.MessagingException:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: Ipaddressxxx, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
         java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
         at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
         at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
         at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
         at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Check the firewall rule if its blocking the port 25

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190568/network-is-unreachable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826331/java-net-socketexception-network-is-unreachable-connect. You are specifying invalid remote host, or you computer has no route to that host, or you computer has no network connection at all, or maybe java process needs to use some proxy.