# Network is unreachable exception

Tags: java, facebook, tomcat, facebook-access-token

When I try to make a call to facebook via `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx8&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=xxx` with a class HttpClient, I am getting a response like `Exception: Network is unreachable`. It was working previously, and suddenly today it stopped working. I didn't change anything to my code and my network config setting, I am wondering what might be the problem. when I check the log, the error is `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable`.

If I try to call url `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx8&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=xxx` directly from the browser, I can get the accesstoken.

I am stuck on this issue. Thanks ahead.

The exception stack trace is below.

```
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:507)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:457)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:157)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:365)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:477)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:280)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:337)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:176)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:736)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at eqs.snp.util.HTTPRequestClient.setContent(HTTPRequestClient.java:132)
    at eqs.snp.sn.facebook.connector.FacebookAPI.refreshAccessToken(FacebookAPI.java:1750)
    at eqs.snp.sn.facebook.facade.FacebookFacade.getRegisterUser(FacebookFacade.java:262)
    at eqs.snp.sn.facebook.struts.action.FbUserAction.fbredirect(FbUserAction.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `jdk` running on the server. Maybe some files are corrupted. So install a new jdk and run the application, it becomes ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Debian, it could be related to IPv6 settings. Per http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=560044

> Package: sun-java6-jdk
>   Version: 6-17-1
>   Severity: important
>
> Netbase has recently introduced the sysctl-setting
>   net.ipv6.bindv6only=1 in /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf and this
>   setting will probably be the default in squeeze.
>
> This setting breaks networking in java, and any traffic will always
>   result in a "java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable".
>
> It should probably be an rc-bug, but setting as important for now,
>   since users can easily rectify the issue.
>
> Quick fix for users hit by this:
>
> sudo sed -i 's/net.ipv6.bindv6only\ =\ 1/net.ipv6.bindv6only\ =\ 0/' \
>   /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf && sudo invoke-rc.d procps restart

Answer (score 0):

There could be a network connection failure in your environment. I am not sure if your call is from a PC or a mobile app over WiFi. You have no option but wait until connection is re-established.

BTW: Are calls from browser and your app made simultaneously?

Alternatively you can check availability of network connection using `ping graph.facebook.com` etc.

You can also view an explanation to a similar query at [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6826494/767881).

Comment: yes. calls from browser and app made simultaneously. I did ping like u said in my server enviroment. It is working. My app is deployed on server side environment. I have restarted the server so many times . still getting the exception :(

Comment: Strange! try changing url, for a test, to something like `http://www.opencaptcha.com/img/20120522232425-20-60.jpgx` and see if connection is established in your app. Also check, if other third party apps are connecting from your system.

Comment: I did call to the url like u mentioned. but the respond is 'Exception: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
'. Any idea ? :( Is it related with the setting of javax.net.ssl.trustStore & javax.net.ssl.keyStore ? I just set javax.net.ssl.trustStore to sever jre/../security/cacerts path though. Ping the above url is working too :(

Comment: when i tested in my local jdk, the code works. seem like issue with getting cacerts in server environment. not sure yet.

Comment: hi, the problem is the jdk running on the server. I suspect as it is working in my local jdk, I reported to my superior. With newly installed jdk, it is working. I am not sure it is because of cacerts or not.