# Java check to see if Scanner still connected

Tags: java, url, connection

I made a method that retrieves certain data from an Ebay search. Here is the code that I am using:

```
public static LinkedList<EbaySearchResult> getResults(String search){
    LinkedList<EbaySearchResult> results = new LinkedList<EbaySearchResult>();
    LinkedList<String> links = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> titles = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> prices = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> images = new LinkedList<String>();
    try{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new URL(String.format("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=%s&_sacat=0", search)).openStream());
        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            String line = reader.nextLine().trim();
            if(line != null && !line.equals("")){
                if(line.contains(CONTAINS_ONE) && line.contains(CONTAINS_TWO)){
                    String[] splitter = line.split(CONTAINS_SPLIT);
                    String[] splitter2 = splitter[1].split(CONTAINS_SPLIT_2);
                    images.add(splitter2[0].trim());
                }
                if(line.contains(INFO_CONTAINS)){
                    String[] splitter = line.split(INFO_SPLIT);
                    String[] splitter2 = splitter[1].split(INFO_SPLIT_2);
                    String[] splitter3 = splitter[1].split(INFO_SPLIT_3);
                    String[] splitter4 = splitter3[1].split(INFO_SPLIT_4);
                    links.add(splitter2[0].trim());
                    titles.add(splitter4[0].trim());
                }
                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(PRICE_INFO)){
                    String next = reader.nextLine().trim();
                    String[] splitter = next.split(PRICE_SPLIT);
                    String[] splitter2 = splitter[1].split(PRICE_SPLIT_2);
                    prices.add(splitter2[0].trim());
                }
                if(line.contains(PRICE_EXTENDED_INFO)){
                    String[] splitter = line.split(PRICE_SPLIT);
                    String[] splitter2 = splitter[1].split(PRICE_SPLIT_2);
                    prices.add(splitter2[0].trim());
                }
            }
        }
        if(!links.isEmpty()){
            try{
            for(int i = 0; i < prices.size(); i++){
                if(titles.get(i) != null && prices.get(i) != null && links.get(i) != null && images.get(i) != null){
                    final String title = titles.get(i);
                    final String price = prices.get(i);
                    final String link = links.get(i);
                    final String image = images.get(i);
                    results.add(new EbaySearchResult(title, price, link, image));
                }
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}
```

The problem is is that my internet keeps dropping for, literally, a split second. I've tried searching other questions on this site for "how to check if you're still connected", or something similiar. I've tried multiple methods but none of the methods seem to work for me. The problem is is that when my internet drops for that split second, the whole method seems to break, and becomes useless (it seems that the Scanner does not automatically recover). What I want to do is add in a check to see if I'm still connected to the site, and if I'm not, I basically want to loop back to the beginning (I know how to do the looping part, but I just need the method that checks for whether or not I am connected) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: There are no stack traces.

EDIT: I know that it is still running and the method is stalling because when I look at my console, the program is still running and basically all the code that is inside my main method, is actually calling the method 'getResults'.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to believe in the existence of the problem as described. What are the symptoms? Internet connections don't 'drop for literally a split second' unless you have some pathological hardware condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just put a loop around your try/catch block and terminate when you want to stop reading from Ebay. If you get disconnected, the stream should throw an exception when you try to read from it, the exception gets caught, and at this point (maybe in a `finally{}`) make sure your resources are freed, then it loops back to the top of the `try{}` where a new Scanner is created and a new connection is made.

By making sure the resources are freed, you probably want an InputStream declaration outside of the try block, and set it to the `Url.openStream()` call so that you can call `close()` on the input stream in a `finally{}` block.

Comment: But that's the thing I don't quite understand, no exceptions are thrown. It seems that the method just stops operating once my internet connection drops for a split second. It's like the method is just stalling or something.

Comment: @JoshM try setting a read timeout to the connection, by doing something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5351894/851273

Comment: Oh I see. Looks very helpful, thanks. But I still have a question about this. What will happen if it does timeout?

Comment: @JoshM the internal call to InputStream.read(), which is blocked, will throw a SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm just playing around with the timeout values and it seems that I sometimes get different results. Basically, the maximum amount of results that I can get is 43. I've noticed that if it doesn't get all those results in the set amount of time, it seems to return a lower number of results. So basically what I believe is that when it times out before getting all the results (due to internet failure) it only returns what it got BEFORE it timed out. So now all I have to do is add in a check to make sure there are infact 43 results, and if there isnt, I could just loop back to the start.